# Django 1.9 how to import in __init__.py

Tags: python, django, django-1.9

I've updated from Django 1.8 to 1.9.

**apps/comment/__init__.py (in 1.8)**

```
from .models import Mixin
```

In Django 1.9 this no longer works but I still want to import `Mixin` in the same way.

So I tried this:

**apps/comment/__init__.py**

```
default_app_config = 'comment.apps.CommentConfig'
```

**apps/comment/apps.py**

```
# Django imports.
from django.apps import AppConfig


class CommentConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'comments'

    def ready(self):
        """
        Perform initialization tasks.
        """
        from .models import CommentMixin
```

This however, does not appear to work, i.e. I cannot do `from comment import Mixin`, why?

Comment: Use the full path `from apps.comment.models import CommentMixin`

Comment: @Gocht I'm aware I can do that, but should above not work? Is there a problem with importing like this?

Comment: I don't have a full reason yet, but I have been working with Django 1.9 and I got the same problem, solved using the full path.

Comment: What does "this no longer works" entail? errors? invalid results?

Comment: @Sayse No errors, but I cannot do ``from comment import CommentMixin`` without using the full path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `from .models import CommentMixin` imports `CommentMixin` so that you can use it inside the `ready()` method. It does not magically add it to the `comment` module so that you can access it as `comments.CommentMixin`

You could assign it to the `comments` module in the `ready()` method.

```
# Django imports.
from django.apps import AppConfig
import comments

class CommentConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'comments'

    def ready(self):
        """
        Perform initialization tasks.
        """
        from .models import CommentMixin
        comments.CommentMixin = CommentsMixin
```

However I would discourage you from doing this, you might end up with hard-to-debug import errors later on. I would just change your imports to `from comment.models import CommentMixin`.